# SQL to get most recent value as of each date in the past

Tags: sql, subquery, presto, lateral-join

I have a table called `event_user_fav_color_changed`. Every row in the table represents the event that a user changes their favorite color. **For every date in a certain range, I'd like to get every user's favorite color as of that date.**

Here's a sample `event_user_fav_color_changed` table:

```
user_id    date          updated_at_datetime    fav_color  
1234       2020-01-01    2020-01-01 12:00:03    blue
1234       2020-01-05    2020-01-05 10:30:00    green
```

Here's a sample table with the users and dates I'm interested in:

```
user_id    date      
1234       2020-01-01
1234       2020-01-04
1234       2020-01-05
1234       2020-01-06
```

Here's the desired output:

```
user_id    date         fav_color
1234       2020-01-01   blue
1234       2020-01-04   blue
1234       2020-01-05   green
1234       2020-01-06   green
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and your desired output in a table format

Answer (score 2):

One option uses a correlated subquery. Assuming that your user/dates table is called `data`, you would do:

```
select
    d.*,
    (   
        select e.fav_color 
        from event_user_fav_color_changed e
        where e.user_id = d.user_id and e.date <= d.date
        order by e.date desc limit 1
    )
from data d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` window function

```
select * from
(
select user_id, date, updated_at_datetime, fav_color, 
row_number() over(partition by user_id,date order by updated_at_datetime desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: Note version requirements - the function `row_number()` needs at least SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you can constrain your lookup to any particular range. So basically each row has to search for the last occurence of an update.

```
select d.date,
  (
    select first_value(fav_color) over (order by updated_at_datetime desc)
    from event_user_fav_color_changed
    where updated_at_datetime < d.date
  ) as fav_as_of
from dates d
```

I don't know anything about Presto in particular but I believe this query ought to work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to express this uses a join and `row_number()`:

```
select uc.*
from (select ufcc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ufcc.user_id order by ufcc.date desc) as seqnum
      from user_dates ud join
           event_user_fav_color_changed ufcc
           on ud.user_id = ufcc.user_id and
              ud.date > ufcc.date
     ) uc
where seqnum = 1;
```

That can be inefficient if there are a lot of color changes.  A join using `lead()` might be more efficient:

```
select ufcc.*
from user_dates ud join
     (select ufcc.*,
             lead(ufcc.date) over (partition by ufcc.user_id order by ufcc.date) as next_date
      from event_user_fav_color_changed ufcc
     ) ufcc
    on ud.user_id = ufcc.user_id and
       ud.date > ufcc.date and
       (ud.date <= ufcc.next_date or ufcc.next_date is null);
```

Or a lateral join:

```
select ufcc.*
from user_dates ud cross join lateral
     (select ufcc.*
      from event_user_fav_color_changed ufcc
      where ud.user_id = ufcc.user_id and
            ud.date > ufcc.date
      order by ufcc.date desc
      limit 1
     ) ud
```