# How to retrieve the last known value for specific date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have two tables: ProductSales and ProductPrice

ProductSales

| SaleDate | SaleProduct | SaleQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 | product1 | 150 |
| 2023-10-01 | product2 | 224 |
| 2023-10-03 | product1 | 91 |
| 2023-10-05 | product3 | 317 |
| 2023-10-05 | product4 | 1200 |
| 2023-10-06 | product1 | 11 |
| 2023-10-09 | product1 | -25 |
| 2023-10-09 | product2 | 190 |
| 2023-10-13 | product1 | 601 |
| 2023-10-15 | product2 | -400 |
| 2023-10-15 | product3 | 35 |

ProductPrice

| PriceDate | Product | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 | product1 | 104 |
| 2023-10-01 | product2 | 53 |
| 2023-10-01 | product3 | 210 |
| 2023-10-01 | product4 | 78 |
| 2023-10-09 | product1 | 100 |
| 2023-10-09 | Product2 | 50 |
| 2023-10-09 | Product3 | 211 |
| 2023-10-09 | Product4 | 75 |
| 2023-10-15 | product2 | 55 |
| 2023-10-15 | product3 | 212 |

Now I have to calculate the monthly sales for every product

```
select SaleProduct, sum(SaleQuantity*isnull(Price,0)) as MonthlySales 
from ProductSales s
left outer join ProductPrice p
    on s.SaleDate = p.PriceDate and s.SaleProduct = p.Product
where saledate between '2023-10-01' and ' 2023-10-31'
group by SaleProduct
```

But the problem is that not for every Sale Date I have corresponding Price Date and join by date sometimes gives me zero price. If so, I have to take the price from last known date before sale date.

How to achieve this in a query?

Comment: You haven't shown the expected results of your sample data.

Comment: Here is a link t a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/-VFPO1HL) with above input data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get value for every date in table with date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69924009/get-value-for-every-date-in-table-with-date-ranges)  and [SQL to get most recent value as of each date in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63717951/sql-to-get-most-recent-value-as-of-each-date-in-the-past)

Comment: Why not store the prices in the Sales table instead of doing these kind of joins

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ps.SaleProduct,ps.SaleQuantity*pp.Price
From ProductSales ps Inner Join ProductPrice pp
  On ps.SaleProduct=pp.Product and
    pp.PriceDate=(Select max(x.PriceDate) From ProductPrice x
           Where x.Product=ps.SaleProduct and x.PriceDate<=ps.SaleDate
                 )
```

It's called a correlated subquery when you refer to outer query values within your inner query.

Comment: This produces an error as Product is not part of sales

Comment: Thank you . That's what I looked for, to refer outer table from inner query . The resulting query is :                                                                                                      
 Select ps.SaleProduct,sum(ps.SaleQuantity*pp.Price) as MonthlySales
From ProductSales ps Inner Join ProductPrice pp
  On ps.SaleProduct=pp.Product and
    pp.PriceDate=(Select max(x.PriceDate) From ProductPrice x
           Where x.Product=ps.SaleProduct and x.PriceDate<=ps.SaleDate
                 )
group by ps.SaleProduct

Answer (score 0):

You had the product names with capital initial once and with small initial in other cases. I put all to "Title" with capital initial.

I tried another approach: Add a column to the product prices equal to the next product price date of the same product using `LEAD(pricedate,1,'9999-12-31') OVER()`, which causes a missing next date to be replaced by a maximum date value, in a subquery, and join the sales table with that subquery with a complex join involving an equi-predicate on the product and a range predicate on the three dates:

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                         
-- your input, not part of end query ..
productsales(SaleDate,SaleProduct,SaleQuantity) AS (
          SELECT CAST('2023-10-01' AS DATE),'Product1',150
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-01' AS DATE),'Product2',224
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-03' AS DATE),'Product1',91
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-05' AS DATE),'Product3',317
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-05' AS DATE),'Product4',1200
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-06' AS DATE),'Product1',11
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-09' AS DATE),'Product1',-25
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-09' AS DATE),'Product2',190
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-13' AS DATE),'Product1',601
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-15' AS DATE),'Product2',-400
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-15' AS DATE),'Product3',35
)
,
productprice(PriceDate,Product,Price) AS (
          SELECT CAST('2023-10-01' AS DATE) ,'Product1',104
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-01' AS DATE) ,'Product2',53
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-01' AS DATE) ,'Product3',210
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-01' AS DATE) ,'Product4',78
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-09' AS DATE) ,'Product1',100
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-09' AS DATE) ,'Product2',50
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-09' AS DATE) ,'Product3',211
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-09' AS DATE) ,'Product4',75
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-15' AS DATE) ,'Product2',55
UNION ALL SELECT CAST('2023-10-15' AS DATE) ,'Product3',212
)
-- end of input
-- real query starts here, replace following comma wiht "WITH"
,
w_next_pricedt AS (
  SELECT
    pricedate AS price_from_dt
  , LEAD(pricedate,1,'9999-12-31') OVER(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY pricedate) AS price_to_dt
  , product
  , price
  FROM productprice
) 
SELECT
  saleproduct
, SUM(SaleQuantity*ISNULL(Price,0)) AS monthlysales
FROM productsales s
JOIN w_next_pricedt p
 ON p.product=s.saleproduct
AND s.saledate >= p.price_from_dt
AND s.saledate <  p.price_to_dt
WHERE s.saledate BETWEEN '2023-10-01' AND ' 2023-10-31'
GROUP BY saleproduct
ORDER BY saleproduct
```

| saleproduct | monthlysales |
| --- | --- |
| Product1 | 83808 |
| Product2 | -628 |
| Product3 | 73990 |
| Product4 | 93600 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_4LisfXW)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. I am not sure if you need something like this. This solution should work on SQL server.

```
with salesData as
(
    select 
        * , 
        row_number() over (partition by a.saleDate , a.saleProduct , a.saleQuantity , b.product order by b.priceDate desc) as seq
    from productSales as a inner join productPrices as b on 
    a.saleProduct = b.Product and a.saleDate >= b.priceDate
)
select 
    a.saleProduct ,
    datename(month , saleDate) as [month] , 
    sum(saleQuantity*unitPrice) as totalPrice 
from salesData as a
where seq = 1
group by a.saleProduct , datename(month , saleDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a price history table. It shows for instance that product1 cost 104 in the date range from 2023-10-01 to 2023-10-08. On 2023-10-09 the price changed to 100 and has thus been valid since then.

You want to select all sales and then join only *one* price to the transaction, namely the current one for the sale date. For this to happen, you need a lateral join (`CROSS APPLY`) in combination with a `TOP` clause.

```
select 
  s.saleproduct,
  sum(s.salequantity * pp.price) as monthly_sales
from productsales s
cross apply
(
  select top(1) *
  from productprice p
  where p.product = s.saleproduct
    and p.pricedate <= s.saledate
  order by p.pricedate desc
) pp
where s.saledate between cast('2023-10-01' as date)
                     and cast('2023-10-31' as date)
group by s.saleproduct
order by s.saleproduct;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/OfBrHFp7 (Thanks to Luuk for providing the fiddle with the input data.)